# se me cierra la app al subir la imagen al un server usando mysqlite

Tags: php, sql, android-studio, base-de-datos, botón

estoy tratando de subir una imagen a una base de datos desde mi app con android studio, pero a la hora de darle a mi boton de subir se me cierra la app y no se por que.

Estoy usando un host gratuito que es miarroba y como base de datos estoy usando phpmyadmin, les paso mi codigo, ayuden porfavor es para un proyecto. ya le di permisos de internet en manifest y ya importe las librerias necesarias.

No me da error pero se cierra al darle al boton subir, pondré estos puntos ya que no me dejaba subir la pregunta me decía que necesitaba mas detalles...
gracias........................................................................................................................................................

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

private Button btnBuscar;
private Button btnSubir;

private ImageView imageView;

private EditText editTextName;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private String UPLOAD_URL ="serverimagenes.webcindario.com/upload.php";

private String KEY_IMAGEN = "foto";
private String KEY_NOMBRE = "nombre";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
    btnSubir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubir);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSubir.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public String getStringImagen(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    //Mostrar el diálogo de progreso
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Subiendo...","Espere por favor...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Descartar el diálogo de progreso
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Mostrando el mensaje de la respuesta
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Descartar el diálogo de progreso
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Convertir bits a cadena
            String imagen = getStringImagen(bitmap);

            //Obtener el nombre de la imagen
            String nombre = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creación de parámetros
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Agregando de parámetros
            params.put(KEY_IMAGEN, imagen);
            params.put(KEY_NOMBRE, nombre);

            //Parámetros de retorno
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creación de una cola de solicitudes
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Agregar solicitud a la cola
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Cómo obtener el mapa de bits de la Galería
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Configuración del mapa de bits en ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == btnBuscar){
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if(v == btnSubir){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Te da algún error si ejecutas en modo `debug`? Evita utilizar negrilla en la pregunta.

Comment: sip siempre se detiene la app

Comment: se me cierra la app

Comment: que te muestra el LogCat??

Comment: "No me da error pero se cierra al darle al boton subir" ¿? :-| Si no usas el LogCat puede ser dificil saber que sucede.